# How do I split a list into sublists at certain points?

Tags: haskell

How do I manually split `[1,2,4,5,6,7]` into `[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]]`? Manually means without using break.

Then, how do I split a list  into sublists according to a predicate? Like so

```
f even [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]] == [[1],[2,3],[4,5],[6,7]]
```

PS: this is not homework, and I've tried for hours to figure it out on my own.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Because there's no code?

Comment: @amindfv I would guess so. If the OP had shown an example of something that they had tried, it would have demonstrated some effort on their part, and would have made it easier for us to help because we would have known what type of help the OP needed. I didn't vote, but if I had, I would have probably downvoted and added a comment like "What have you tried?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question, this is rather an element-wise *transformation* than a split. The appropriate function to do this is

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Now, you need a function `(a -> b)` where `b` is `[a]`, as you want to transform an element into a singleton list containing the same type. Here it is:

```
mkList :: a -> [a]
mkList a = [a]
```

so

```
map mkList [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] == [[1],[2],...]
```

As for your second question: If you are not allowed (homework?) to use `break`, are you then allowed to use `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` which form both halves of the result of `break`.

Anyway, for a solution without them ("manually"), just use simple recursion with an accumulator:

```
f p [] = []
f p (x:xs) = go [x] xs
    where go acc [] = [acc]
          go acc (y:ys) | p y = acc : go [y] ys
                        | otherwise = go (acc++[y]) ys
```

This will traverse your entire list tail recursively, always remembering what the current sublist is, and when you reach an element where `p` applies, outputting the current sublist and starting a new one.

Note that go first receives `[x]` instead of `[]` to provide for the case where the first element already satisfies `p x` and we don't want an empty first sublist to be output.

Also, this operates on the original list (`[1..7]`) instead of `[[1],[2]...]`. But you can use it on the transformed one as well:

```
> map concat $ f (odd . head) [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]]
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7]]
```

Comment: There is this `break :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])` and it seems less than optimal as it returns a pair. `f` is supposed to represent a function which takes a predicate `even` and a list and returns a list split at the elements for which the predicate applied to the element returns True.

Comment: @A.B., you cannot really do what you want with `break` since it is high-level construction (built over lower-level mapping primitives or with recursion directly) which does not have the semantics you need. As was already said, your best bet would be using `map`.

Comment: @A.B. Added answer to your second question

Comment: Thanks, this works. My question is one of the earlier exercises from "Real World Haskell". The "no break" isn't a requirement, I just thought that there had to be better ways. I'm surprised that the solution is so complicated - it's above what a reader could be expected to be capable of doing at this point.

Comment: Can you explain what is happening there `p y = acc : go [y] ys`?

Comment: `| p y` is a guard: so this is the case where `y` satisfies `p` and a new sublist shall start with `y`. That means that the current sublist `acc` is finished. So `acc` goes to the output (`acc :`) and recursion is restarted with a new sublist `[y]` and the rest of the elements to process (`go [y] ys`).

Comment: `mkList = return :: a -> [a]` in this case, incidentally.

Answer (score 2):

First:

```
map (: [])
```

Second:

```
f p xs = 
  let rs = foldr (\[x] ~(a:r) -> if (p x) then ([]:(x:a):r) else ((x:a):r))
           [[]] xs
  in case rs of ([]:r) -> r ; _ -> rs
```

---

`foldr`'s operation is easy enough to visualize:

```
foldr g z [a,b,c, ...,x] = g a (g b (g c (.... (g x z) ....)))
```

So when writing the combining function, it is expecting two arguments, 1st of which is "current element" of a list, and 2nd is "result of processing the rest". Here,

```
g [x] ~(a:r) | p x    = ([]:(x:a):r)
             | otherwise = ((x:a):r)
```

So visualizing it working from the right, it just adds into the most recent sublist, and opens up a new sublist if it must. But since lists are actually accessed from the left, we keep it lazy with the lazy pattern,     `~(a:r)`. Now it works even on infinite lists:

```
Prelude> take 9 $ f odd $ map (:[]) [1..]
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10],[11,12],[13,14],[15,16],[17,18]]
```

The pattern for the 1st argument reflects the peculiar structure of your expected input lists.

Answer (score 2):

For the first, you can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [[x] | x <- [1,2,3,4,5,6]]
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
```

For the second problem, you can use the [Data.List.Split](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/0.2.2/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html) module provided by the `split` package:

```
import Data.List.Split

f :: (a -> Bool) -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
f predicate = split (keepDelimsL $ whenElt predicate) . concat
```

This first [concat](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3aconcat)s the list, because the functions from `split` work on lists and not list of lists. The resulting single list is the split again using functions from the split package.